# scipy.interpolate.griddata sensitivity to original grid

Tags: python, scipy

I am using scipy.interpolate.griddata in order to interpolate data from an original grid to a sub-region of that grid but at a higher resolution. In order to speed the computation, instead of using the whole original data, I used only the part that contains the target region (with a buffer). To my surprise, I obtain different results if I use linear interpolation, even in the middle of my subregion.

The code that follows illustrate this. I am wondering if this is to be expected or if it is a bug in griddata. Notice that if I use 'nearest' instead of 'linear' in the code the differences are null, as I expected.

Any help appreciated.

```
# modification to expample 1 of 
# http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/item/Matplotlib_Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data.html
# to show problems with griddata

import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy.ma as ma

# generate inital fields on 2d grid
x = np.arange(-2,2.1,0.1)
y = np.arange(-2,2.1,0.1)
x2d, y2d = np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = np.abs(x*np.exp(-x2d**2-y2d**2)) + 1

# define target grid 
# (sub region of initial grid but with finer mesh)
x_target = np.arange(-1,1,0.01)
y_target = np.arange(-1,1,0.01)
x2d_target, y2d_target = np.meshgrid(x_target, y_target)

# define interpolation function
def f_int(data, x, y, xt, yt):
    nj, ni = data.shape
    nij = ni * nj
    zi = data.reshape((nij))
    xi = x.ravel()
    yi = y.ravel()
    xo = xt.ravel()
    yo = yt.ravel()
    zo = griddata((xi, yi), zi, (xo, yo), 
              method = 'linear', fill_value = np.nan)
    zo = zo.reshape(xt.shape)
    return zo

# interpolate on target grid using the whole initial field
z_int_full = f_int(z, x2d, y2d, x2d_target, y2d_target)

# interpolate on taget grid using a subset of initial field
buffer = 5
x2d_sub = x2d[buffer:-buffer, buffer:-buffer]
y2d_sub = y2d[buffer:-buffer, buffer:-buffer]
z_sub = z[buffer:-buffer, buffer:-buffer]
z_int_sub = f_int(z_sub, x2d_sub, y2d_sub, x2d_target, y2d_target)

# show the results
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(fig.get_size_inches() * 2)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
plt.pcolormesh(x2d, y2d, z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('initial data')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
plt.pcolormesh(x2d_target, y2d_target, z_int_full)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('interpolate from full grid')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
plt.pcolormesh(x2d_target, y2d_target, z_int_sub)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('interpolate from sub grid')

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
diff = (z_int_full - z_int_sub)
rel = diff / z_int_full * 100
plt.pcolormesh(x2d_target, y2d_target, rel)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title('relative difference between \n interpolated data [%]')


plt.show()
```

**Edit**
added the figure produced by the code. As you can see on the bottom right graph, there are relative error of the order of 0.1% which I am not expecting. I tried to simplify the problem to formulate my question but on the data I am working on, this translate into difference of the order of 1 deg_K for interpolated surface temperature, which is a problem for me.

[image]

Comment: Update for future readers: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7857 . It seems that the triangulation underlying `griddata` for regularly gridded input data is ill-defined, and can lead to such deviations in the result. In particular, the triangulation works globally, so even though the inner points are the same for interpolation, the triangulation used for the calculation might differ.